# WebStorm's Safe Delete doesn't check XML file

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm deleting a CSS file that is referenced in an XML file. I select "Safe delete (with usage search)" and "Search in comments and strings" but the reference in the XML file is not found.

The XML file is in a directory included in the project. The XML file contains the complete file name in a string.

Are there some settings for Safe Delete somewhere or something more general that might exclude XML files?

Thanks for any help.

```
<resourceSet name="HeaderStylesCss" type="css">
    <resource path="~/Legacy/Content/Css/HeaderStyles.css"/>
</resourceSet>
```

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that the feature doesn't understand paths starting with ~.

Comment: I was hoping it would just pick up on the file name in a string as it does with other code files when you select the option to "Search in comments and strings". I'm not expecting it to know for certain that it is a reference to that exact file.

Answer (score 0):

`path` value is treated as simple string, so CSS file usage is not found and thus not taken into account when deleting a file.
You can try injecting **File reference** language in `path=""` value manually via `Alt+Enter`, **Inject language or reference**:

[image]

but paths starting with `~` won't work there, I'd suggest using relative paths rather than absolute